# content control in word (2007) linking a value in a drop down box to a textbox

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

ive searched listed code and word help and tried to manipulate others code
ive got as far as creating a developer combo box with two fields the display name and a value.
i have also managed to use the selected information into another combo box so i can chose the value from the list (of one) but i have to select it.
i want to display the value in a text box, as there is only one value.

what i require seems simple to me but i'm really struggling to sort it.

i need a drop down box (combo box) that has a list containing two values.
i want the first value to be displayed so the user can select it.
i want the corresponding value to be displayed in a text box on another line.

eg.

data: fred - 21a, bill - 32c, goerge - 32 19f

i want to select : fred, bill, george. from a list
and have the value (21a, 32c, 32 19f) that matches it in a separate text box

the data table is static and wont change.
i just need to select the relevant values for printing